# Can't include a md file in a quarto book page

Tags: quarto

I'd like to include the readme.md file in the index of a quarto book (so I do not need to duplicate content).

According to [these instructions in the official documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html), that should be possible.

This is my current structure:

```
/folders
...
_quarto.yml
index.qmd
README.md
...
```

This is my index.qmd file:

```
# Preface {.unnumbered}

This is a Quarto book.

{{< include README.md >}}
```

Regretfully, the readme file is not included. Instead, {{< include README.md >}} is printed as a text.

EDIT:

I have created this github project:https://github.com/ccamara/quarto-book-test . You can see the outputs here: https://ccamara.github.io/quarto-book-test/

This is what I've done so far:

1. Create a default project: `quarto create-project mybook --type book`
2. Create a `README.md`file in the project's root
3. Edit `index.md` (in the project's root) and added `{{< include README.md >}}`
4. Run `quarto preview`
5. I get a warning stating `WARNING: Shortcode include is not recognized.`
6. `index.md` does not render `README.md`contents, instead it displays the include shortcode as a regular text (see screnshot below).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to omit the underscore? The name after `include`  should match the actual filename.

Comment: And, just to add to @tarleb's answer: the reason we use underscores in our examples is that by default, quarto does not render any `.qmd` file starting with underscores. So if you want (e.g.) VS code to use syntax highlighting for your includes, _and_ you don't want quarto to render your includes, then you choose a filename like `_some_include.qmd`. For `.md` files, though, quarto does not render them by default, and so the underscore wouldn't be particularly useful.

Comment: Oh, I missread instructions about the underscore! Even without it, files are not included. I've tried with qmd files and rm files,  in the same level as the index.qmd file (project's root). I'm creating a book.

Comment: I have updated the description with code and detailed steps to reproduce (basically, it is a default template with an include code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce, unfortunately. I recreated your example, and got this:

[image]

This happens in `quarto preview` and `quarto render` both. What version and OS are you running? Can you run this and report the result? Thanks.

```
$ quarto --version
```

Comment: Updating from 0.9.309 to 0.9.464 fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip!